# How can I delete a file that is currently in use by another process in cpp win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, wix, windows-installer, delete-file

While uninstalling my msi application , the log files(.txt) in Program Data folder are not getting deleted after calling DeleteFile() function. By using GetErrorCode() I  could check its returning error code 32 which implies the file is in use.Is there a way I can delete these log files while uninstallation? Theory or source -Any kind of help would be appreciated.

I tried using the below code but it didn't work. Even fclose() operation didn't yield any positive results.

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT file_op = {
        NULL,
        FO_DELETE,
        dir,
        "",
        FOF_NOCONFIRMATION |
        FOF_NOERRORUI |
        FOF_SILENT,
        false,
        0,
        "" };
    SHFileOperation(&file_op);
```

Comment: Windows doesn't allow you to remove a file which is opened by any process, even your own. To be able to remove a file, all references to the file must be closed and removed first.

Comment: You are probably looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490755/898348

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy a file or folder that is locked under windows programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259253/how-do-i-copy-a-file-or-folder-that-is-locked-under-windows-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need to know which process is holding my file so that I can close the process handle.Any way to do that?

Comment: This is another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450381/windows-event-viewer-holds-a-lock-on-my-exe-file/18452006#18452006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't delete a file that is currently in use by another process. You could try to use Use `MoveFileEx` with the `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT flag`.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the threads:
[How can I force the deletion of locked files in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215461/how-can-i-force-the-deletion-of-locked-files-in-c-c#215466)